# Java gui Jbutton

Tags: java, swing

I have a program but I can't combine the `textfield` and the `button` in the same frame like in top `textfield` and below that the `button`:

Here is my source code:

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
public class FirstGui extends JFrame
{
     JTextField texts;
 JButton button;   

    public FirstGui()
    {
        texts = new JTextField(15);
        add(texts);
        button = new JButton("Ok");
        add(button);

    }
    public static void main(String args [])
    {
        FirstGui gui = new FirstGui();
        gui.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        gui.setSize(200,125);
        gui.setVisible(true);

    }
}
```

Comment: see: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html

Comment: It is always a good idea to state what you expect to happen and what actually happens. Far better than "I can't" or "doesn't work".

Answer (score 2):

Add a layout like `FlowLayout`:

```
public FirstGui()
{
    setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    texts = new JTextField(15);
    add(texts);
    button = new JButton("Ok");
    add(button);

}
```

at the very beginning of your constructor, before anything else.

Comment: i already tried it but the error is java.lang.error: do not use FirstGui.setLayout() use FirstGui.getContentPane().setLayout()instead

Comment: Don't do FirstGui.setLayout(), that can't work. FirstGui refers to the class, not an instance. Just write setLayout(new FlowLayout()), as it is.

Comment: anything that can i try ?

Answer (score 2):

The default layout is `BorderLayout` for `JFrame`. When you add components to a `BorderLayout`, if you don't specify their `BorderLayout` position, like `BorderLayout.SOUTH`, the component will automatically be add to `BorderLayout.CENTER`.  Bthe thing is though, each position can only have one component. So when you add `texts` it gets added to the `CENTER`. Then when you add `button`, it gets added to the `CENTER` but `texts` gets kicked out. So to fix, you can do

```
add(texts, BorderLayout.NORTH);
add(button, BorderLayout.CENTER);
```

See [**Laying out Components Within a Container**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html) to learn more about layout managers.

---

**UPDATE**

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class FirstGui extends JFrame {

    JTextField texts;
    JButton button;

    public FirstGui() {
        texts = new JTextField(15);
        add(texts, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        button = new JButton("Ok");
        add(button, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        FirstGui gui = new FirstGui();
        gui.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        gui.pack();
        gui.setVisible(true);

    }
}
```

Comment: same java.lang.Error :ccccccccccc

Comment: I don't know what you're doing wrong then, it works fine for me.

Comment: i know setLayout(new FlowLayout()); will work but ill get java.lang.error :((

Comment: sir im using JCreator .

Comment: Use an industry standard IDE like Netbeans or Eclipse. It's free to download

Comment: I don't know, I've never used it.

Comment: sir please check on my new syntax .

Comment: Why don't you copy and paste my code to see if it works.

Comment: ohh sorry sir hehe im new in this blog i dont know the rules yet . i see

Comment: java.lang.Error: Do not use FirstGui.add() use FirstGui.getContentPane().add()instead

at javax.swing.JFrame.createRootPaneException(JFrame.java:465)

Comment: java.lang.Error: Do not use FirstGui.add() use FirstGui.getContentPane().add() instead
 at javax.swing.JFrame.createRootPaneException(JFrame.java:465)
 at javax.swing.JFrame.addImpl(JFrame.java:491)
 at java.awt.Container.add(Container.java:518)
 at FirstGui.<init>(FirstGui.java:11)
 at FirstGui.main(FirstGui.java:18)